# The committee who have been working hard or the committee which has been working hard?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, collective-nouns

When referring to a committee that has been working hard, which of the following would you say?

1. The committee **which has** been working hard.
2. The committee **who have** been working hard.

The committee is made up of people I know, it is not a group of unknown people so I feel strange referring to them as *which,* but my husband insists that is the correct usage.

Comment: You could run into UK/US stuff here.  In the US "committee" (like "team") is treated as singular, but those UK guys are kinda weird with regard to this stuff.

Comment: Links to related questions about the choice between "who" and "which": [What is the correct relative pronoun for “government”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68790), ['Who' or 'which' in reference to companies](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138110) and about collective nouns: [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338)

Comment: You could run into US/UK stuff here. In the UK "committee" (like "team") is usually treated as either singular or plural (ie afforded the relevant verb-form) depending on whether the whole or the individuals are being signified, but some US guys are less flexible with regard to this stuff. Both 1 and 2 above are perfectly acceptable grammatically in 'BrE' (actually to anyone accepting 'notional agreement', which many Americans do up to a point, sometimes without realising it), but 2 gives the more personal touch (and is more logical, as it is the people on the committee doing the work).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are addressing the "hard work", which is the product of individuals, it may be preferable to say ***who have***.

When discussing the committee as an entity - say, the consensus, or location of - **which has** may be preferable.